# Update function in Kendo UI Grid (using with AngularJs) never fires, using with Local Data

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid, which is bound to an KendoObservableArray. I am using inline edit mode. And my options are declared as below :

```
valueMapCtrl.lookupMappingDetails = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);

        valueMapCtrl.gridOptions = {
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        options.success(valueMapCtrl.lookupMappingDetails);
                    },
                    update: function (options) {
                        console.log("Update", options);
                        options.success(options.data);
                    },
                    create: function (options) {
                        console.log("Create", options);
                        options.data.mappingId = mappingId;
                        mappingId = mappingId + 1;
                        options.success(options.data);
                    },
                    destroy: function (options) {
                        console.log("Delete", options);
                        options.success(options.data);
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                        // this is optional - if we need to remove any parameters (due to partial OData support in WebAPI
                        console.log(options, type);
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return JSON.stringify({models: options});
                        }
                    },
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    console.log("change: " + e.action);
                    // do something with e
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    // handle error
                    alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
                },
                //data: valueMapCtrl.dynamicData,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "mappingId",
                        fields: {
                            mappingId: {editable: false, nullable: false, defaultValue: 0},
                            Col1: {
                                type: "string",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            Col2: {
                                type: "string",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                batch: false

            }),
            columns: [{
                field: "col1",
                title: "Column 1"
            }, {
                field: "col2",
                title: "Column 2"
            }, {
                command: /*"destroy"*/ ["edit", "destroy"],
                title: "&nbsp;",
                width: "200px"
            }],
            selectable: "multiple cell",
            allowCopy: "true",
            //save: function (e) {
            //    console.log("Save", e);
            //},
            toolbar: ["create"],
            height: 300,
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            editable: "inline"
        };
```

1. Add record : create fires correctly
2. Delete record: destroy fires correctly
3. Update record : nothing happens, no error, all I see in change event sync() action.

But If I declare save as well in my options, that fires correctly.

```
    save: function (e) {
            console.log("Save", e); //This fires on each update
        },
```

I am not sure what is wrong in above declaration; browsed through a lot of forums/questions for similar issue but could not get it working. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working, posting here in case anyone gets the same issue.

```
valueMapCtrl.lookupMappingDetails = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
```

I changed this observable array to normal array and things worked fine after that :

```
valueMapCtrl.lookupMappingDetails =[];// new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
```

Also, with observable array, I was facing another issue; where cancelling of edit was removing ALL ROWS from the grid. That also worked correctly after this change. Not sure of the reason though and couldn't find any explanation in telerik docs (Whatever I could search).